# How to split buffered string to send as multiple packets at a certain byte size?

Tags: javascript, react-native, buffer

I'm sending data to a BLE device and I believe it has a byte limit of 28 bytes per packets. How can i split this buffer into specific byte sizes to send?

```
 let string = 'How do I split this string?';
 let commandInBase64 = Buffer.from(string).toString('base64'); // too big to send

 device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(serviceUUID, commandUUID, commandInBase64)
   .catch(handleError);
```

Comment: can the string contain characters outside of the ASCII range *(charCode > 127)*? These will be encoded with more than 1 byte and should not be split. Besides that, you can simply [slice the buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end) into 21byte long chunks and convert these to base64.

Comment: @Thomas I'm working with SSID so I believe so and even then the edge cases I can handle later. So something like this? Where commandInBase64 would be the first packet?
```
let string = 'How do I split this string?';
let bufferedString = Buffer.from(string);

let subString = bufferedString.slice(0, 22)
let commandInBase64 = subString.tostring('base64');
```

Comment: 21, not 22 characters, but yes